# I need help closing up some ports on a debian 10 server

Tags: networking, port, services, systemd, debian-buster

I ran nmap on my server and i need help closing up a few ports

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE       VERSION
25/tcp   filtered smtp
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server
```

The list above has been edited and ports that should be open have been removed from the list,in the list is only ports that shouldn't be open

If possible I would like to close these ports and disable the services listening on these ports.

Comment: So what's the problem? You have each service listed. Have your tried to find the init.d script that starts each service? The actual startup scheme is dependent on which init system is employed, e.g. SystemV or SystemD or Busybox or ??

Comment: The ports aren’t open. They are filtered. Meaning nmap doesn’t have a clue if they are open or not but it definitely is unable to communicate with them. There may not be anything listening at all. It’s simply blocked on the firewall which is normal. The fact many of these ports are windows specific seems to suggest that’s the case.